# Change language - screen goes white

Tags: angularjs, ionic-v1

### How to properly use a checkbox to change $rootScope value in AngularJS

I am trying to create a multilingual section to an app, that allows the users to front to choose their language of preference when the app loads.

In doing so, I set the `$rootScope.language` to their preferred language.

Since that occurs only once at the load of the app, I wanted to add a preferences section where they can alter their choice, as needed.

In my Ionic V1 framework, I had created this in my template for the users to choose their language:

```
<ion-list>
        <ion-radio ng-model="lang" ng-value="'en_US'" ng-click="updateLanguage('en_US')">English</ion-radio>
        <ion-radio ng-model="lang" ng-value="'es_MX'" ng-click="updateLanguage('es_MX')">Espanol</ion-radio>
        <ion-radio ng-model="lang" ng-value="'fr_CA'" ng-click="updateLanguage('fr_CA')">Francais</ion-radio>
</ion-list>
```

Here is part of my app.js that sets the `$rootScope` value for the language:

```
.run(function($rootScope) {
   $rootScope.language = 'en_US';
})
```

Along with that, I was using this in my controllers.js:

```
.controller('PreferencesCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $state, $ionicPlatform, $ionicLoading) {
  
  alert('PreferencesCtrl');

  $scope.lang = $rootScope.language;

  //Update Language
  $scope.updateLanguage = function(lang) {
    $scope.lang = lang;
    $rootScope.language = lang;
  };

});
```

The issue I am running into is that I can successfully change the language once, but if I attempt to change it again, the whole page goes white, and nothing is being rendered. It also appears that by setting the `$rootScope`, it also changes the view that is being rendered, as the back button goes away on the current screen.

My guess is that I am not setting the `$rootScope.language` in the updateLanguage function as the information is not being logged to the console on the second attempt to change the language.

If I change the updateLangauge to this:

```
  //Update Language
  $scope.updateLanguage = function(lang) {
    $scope.language = lang;
  };
```

Then I don't experience any of the white screen issues, however, the language is only changed for that particular view - not across the entire app.

Any thoughts on where I may be approaching this incorrectly?

**UPDATE**: It appears that after the $rootScope is being set again in the updateLangauge function that my PreferencesCtrl is then not being executed. I added an alert to the controller to see if it was firing after the $rootScope was set for the second time (when the screen goes white) and the alert never fires. So, it's like the controller is gone after you update the $rootScope.

Answer (score 0):

What i think is going on here, is you're not updating your ng-model.
Whenever you click a language, you update your ng-model, and also pass the language to a method to update the $rootScope.language.
Change your method to update both:

```
$scope.updateLanguage = function(lang) {
   $rootScope.language = lang;
   $scope.lang = lang;
};
```

This should update both the UI ng-model and the rootscope value, making it available everywhere.

The only reason i can think of why your page goes white is because you have some kind of error in the debug console. check that. And you also have a typo in your App.js: it says $rootScope.langauge (should be language).

Furthermore, it might also be interesting to just keep a list of languages in your controller, rather than hardcoding them in the html.
So you could iterate over that, and use those values to update the rootscope.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo. It looks like that was just in my example here, and not my code base. I am not seeing an errors in the debug console. I should have clarified on the white screen, it's only the content `<ion-content>` area of the app. The top header bar and lower tabs are still in place.

Comment: And what's the code for that ion-content? is that a package, or a custom element? seems to me like there's something wrong with the code there, instead of the code you showed.